# Replacing a variable with a value in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string that has certain variables like `"This is string containing $variable$"`. I want to replace this `$variable$` with a new string. If I use replaceall method like `str.replaceall("$variable$","new_value")` it is not getting replaced. But if I give without `$` symbols, it is replacing. But my output is like this, `$new_value$`.
I need it without the `$` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

String.replaceAll() takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as a parameter, and $ has a special meaning there. Just escape dollar signs with \:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\$variable\\$", replacement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
str.replace("$variable$","new_value");
```

because **String.replaceAll()** expects a regular expression as the first parameter, and the **$** character on regular expression stands for "match at the end of the string"

Comment: This will not compile as String.replace takes a char only and not a string.

Comment: Are you sure? public String replace(CharSequence target,                 CharSequence replacement). please, check the API before downvoting.

Comment: Some of these new methods that older generation does not recall and never use. Consider linking. Upvoting.